# How to automaticaly set VIM file type?

Tags: vim

I like to create my own documentation using the VIM help page syntax. When I open a file with VIM, I must use the command `set filetype=help` to switch from plain text to a help page colored syntax (see picture below). How can I tell VIM to set the filetype automatically for my help file ? Is it possible to use a special file extension or to add something in the beginning of the file ?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this in your `.vimrc`.

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.txt set filetype=help
```

This will do all `txt` files though, but you can change it above if you want to target more specific filenames.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a [modeline](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Modeline_magic):

```
" vim: set ft=help:
```

...or, of course, configure some extensions like @alex pointed out.

But in this case I would rather prefer this approach in order to make the files more portable.

Comment: Just scroll to the bottom of any Vim help file and copy the modeline from there.

Comment: I tried to copy either your modeline or the one in the bottom on a Vim help file and this does not work with my custom file.

Comment: After saving the changes and reloading the file, I suppose you mean…

Comment: Of course I tried after saving and reloading the file.

Comment: Then I don't know... It works for me (vim 8.0)... I figure out you have `syntax on` by default in your .vimrc too...